# How can I hide <tr> if it's <td> is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that gets data outputted to it dynamically based on data that is being pulled from my database. I have three hard coded `<tr>` but I want to hide them if there isn't any data outputted to their `<td>` from the database.

This is my HTML

```html
                <table class="table text-light text-end" id="data_table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            {{#each response4}}
                            <th class='title' scope="col">{{commodity}}</th>
                            {{/each}}
                            <th scope="col">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="text-end">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">AUX</th>
                            {{#each response6}}
                            <td class="whole">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                            {{/each}}
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">UEM</th>
                            {{#each response4}}
                            <td class="whole">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                            {{/each}}
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">UT</th>
                            {{#each response5}}
                            <td class="whole">{{fb_plus_fr}}</td>
                            {{/each}}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

This is an example I pulled from the inspect tool when the page loads and gets data from the database. The first `<tr>` doesn't have any `<td>` and should be hidden.

```html
                   <tbody class="text-end">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">AUX</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">UEM</th>
                            <td class="whole">8215</td>
                            <td class="whole">5367</td>
                            <td class="whole">31193</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">UT</th>
                            <td class="whole">8215</td>
                            <td class="whole">5367</td>
                            <td class="whole">31193</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

This is how I'm attempting it but this doesn't work. It won't hide that first  that doesn't have any data. Any advice on how to fix this is greatly appreciated!

```
 window.onload = () => {

        $("#data_table > tbody > tr ").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('td').is(":empty")){
                $(this.hide())
            }
        })  
    };
```

Comment: The class="whole" on each td is to round the number that gets outputted to a whole number. $(".whole").text(function (i, curr) {
            return parseFloat(curr).toFixed(0)
        }) In case this was causing confusion

Comment: You are apparently using some kind of framework other than vanilla JavaScript or jQuery. Please [edit] your question to include the tag for that framework so that those with expertise in the framework can know to provide that expertise.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
 <tr th:if="${yourtable.empty}">
            <td colspan="2">No Content Available</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: It's almost always better to add an explanation of code, especially if the answer uses a technique from a framework the question asker has failed to tag their question with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to go about this would be to have an if block wrapped around the `<tr>` that checks if the data is empty before displaying the `<tr>`.